# c#: DataGridView custom cell lose custom property

Tags: c#, datagridview

Starting from this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7f4ff237-85b1-4db1-b114-2666d883894b/putting-radio-button-in-datagrid-view) I made a custom DataGridViewColumn of radio button type (column and cell).

```
public class DataGridViewRadioButtonColumnEx : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public DataGridViewRadioButtonColumnEx()
    {
        this.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewRadioButtonCell();
        this.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}

public delegate void RadioButtonClickedHandler(bool state);
public class DataGridViewRadioButtonCellEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    bool _bChecked;
    public DataGridViewRadioButtonCellEventArgs(bool bChecked)
    {
        _bChecked = bChecked;
    }

    public bool Checked
    {
        get { return _bChecked; }
    }
}

public class DataGridViewRadioButtonCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    Point radioButtonLocation;
    Size radioButtonSize;
    bool _checked = false;
    public bool Checked
    {
        get { return _checked; }
        set { _checked = value; }
    }

    string _groupName = "";
    public string GroupName
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupName;
        }
        set
        {
            _groupName = value;
        }
    }

    Point _cellLocation = new Point();
    System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.RadioButtonState _cbState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.RadioButtonState.UncheckedNormal;
    public event RadioButtonClickedHandler OnRadioButtonClicked;

    public DataGridViewRadioButtonCell()
    {
    }

    protected override void Paint(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle clipBounds, System.Drawing.Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates dataGridViewElementState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, dataGridViewElementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);

        Point p = new Point();
        Size s = RadioButtonRenderer.GetGlyphSize(graphics, System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.RadioButtonState.UncheckedNormal);

        p.X = cellBounds.Location.X + (cellBounds.Width / 2) - (s.Width / 2);
        p.Y = cellBounds.Location.Y + (cellBounds.Height / 2) - (s.Height / 2);

        _cellLocation = cellBounds.Location;
        radioButtonLocation = p;
        radioButtonSize = s;

        if (_checked)
            _cbState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.RadioButtonState.CheckedNormal;
        else
            _cbState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.RadioButtonState.UncheckedNormal;

        RadioButtonRenderer.DrawRadioButton(graphics, radioButtonLocation, _cbState);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = new Point(e.X + _cellLocation.X, e.Y + _cellLocation.Y);

        if (p.X >= radioButtonLocation.X && p.X <= radioButtonLocation.X + radioButtonSize.Width && p.Y >= radioButtonLocation.Y && p.Y <= radioButtonLocation.Y + radioButtonSize.Height)
        {
            _checked = !_checked;

            if (OnRadioButtonClicked != null)
            {
                OnRadioButtonClicked(_checked);
                this.DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
            }
        }
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e, int rowIndex)
    {
        base.OnKeyUp(e, rowIndex);
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            _checked = true;

            if (OnRadioButtonClicked != null)
            {
                OnRadioButtonClicked(_checked);
                this.DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To Set the status of the Check-Box Header column
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="flagIndicator">True - to mark checked state. False : To mark it as Unchecked.</param>
    public void SetRadioButton(bool flagIndicator)
    {
        _checked = flagIndicator;

        this.DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
    }
}
```

It work fine, I added custom property called "GroupName" (used to now the group that radio button belong) but in runtime, somewhere, is cleared.

```
public class CustomDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnCellClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.RowIndex > -1) && (e.ColumnIndex > -1))
        {
            if ((this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]).OwningColumn is DataGridViewRadioButtonColumnEx)
            {
                DataGridViewRadioButtonCell cell = this[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewRadioButtonCell;
                cell.Checked = !cell.Checked;
                if (((DataGridViewRadioButtonCell)cell).Checked)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.RowCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (cell.GroupName == (this[e.ColumnIndex, i] as DataGridViewRadioButtonCell).GroupName)
                            (this[e.ColumnIndex, i] as DataGridViewRadioButtonCell).Checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnCellClick(e);
        this.InvalidateColumn(e.ColumnIndex);
    }
}
```

How can I detect where the property GroupName is cleared?

Thank you.
Kendo

**LE:**
I found it! I must override clone method:

```
    public override object Clone()
    {
        var clone = (DataGridViewRadioButtonCell)base.Clone();

        clone.Checked = _checked;
        clone.GroupName = _groupName;
        clone.CellType = _cellType;

        return clone;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio:
Right-click on an occurence of your Property -> Find All References.
Alternatively you could put a Breakpoint in the Setter of `GroupName` and observe any calls that change it during debugging.

Comment: OK, it's really hard to tell from your example though, since the Setter never is accessed in it. Are you sure it gets set in the first place?

Comment: Setter is accessed only when it is intialized. `                        row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewRadioButtonCell() { GroupName = "g1" });`